# Search with nested object: Can't get good syntax to get record I want

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have this mapping for my publication model:

```
mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :publisher_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :state
    indexes :title
    indexes :created_at, type: 'date'
    indexes :updated_at, type: 'date'
    indexes :formats, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :pid, type: 'integer'
        indexes :key_type
        indexes :value, type: 'string', analyzer: 'whitespace'
        indexes :state
        indexes :protection
        indexes :nature
        indexes :start_sale_at, type: 'date'
        indexes :issued_on, type: 'date'
        indexes :format_aliases do
            indexes :value, analyzer: 'whitespace'
        end
        indexes :cost do
            indexes :id, type: 'integer'
            indexes :country
            indexes :format
            indexes :amount, type: 'integer'
        end
    end
    indexes :collections do
        indexes :collection_id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :collection_title
    end
    indexes :contributors do
        indexes :contributor_id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :contributor_first_name, analyzer: 'whitespace'
        indexes :contributor_last_name, analyzer: 'whitespace'
    end
end
```

I want to get all publication where state is not 'destroyed', and where one of the format nature is of type 'epub' and with a state set to 'sell'.

I can get none destroyed publication doing this

```
tire.search do
    query do
        boolean do
            must_not {term :state, 'destroyed'}
        end
    end
end
```

I can get all publication having a format where state is 'sell' and nature is 'epub' by doing this:

```
tire.search do
    nested path: 'formats' do
        query do
            match 'formats.nature', 'epub'
            match 'formats.state', 'sell'
        end
   end
end
```

but I can't merge both together to get the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the solution:

```
nested_filter = Tire::Search::Query.new do
  filtered do
    query { all }
    filter :term, {'formats.nature' => 'epub'}
    filter :term, {'formats.state' => 'sell'}
  end
end

tire.search(load: true) do
  query do
    filtered do
      query do
        boolean do
          must_not { term :state, 'processing'}
        end
      end
      filter :nested, {path: 'formats'}.merge({ query: nested_filter.to_hash})
    end
  end
end
```